# How import a external react component to Asp.Net page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, web, frontend

I wanted to import an external React component, generated in webpack (Bundle.js) to my Asp.net MVC application.
I'm trying to import the "Bundle.js" file to my page and render the React component in the babel script tag, but nothing happens.
What is the correct way to import an external component from a webpack library into a View?

Comment: so, what have you tried so far (in terms of coding)?

Comment: I added the Bundle.js in my project, and in my View, I wrote `<script type =" text / babel> `. Here I tried to render the component, like this: ReactDOM.render (<MyComponent />, document. GetElementById ("app"));

Answer (score 0):

try writing this :

```
<script type="text/babel" src="{% static "bundle.js" %}"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please provide context for this answer and how it solves the OPs question?